# Problems installing angular-cropperjs (ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cropperjs

I'm trying to use angular-cropperjs but keep getting an error when I install it with npm install angular-cropperjs --save

[this is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LXpZ.png)

I read on the internet I could use --force to fix the problem, but it seems it's not working. Here's a screenshot of when I do that:
[Already tried using --force](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgUO9.png)

I also tried using --legacy-peer-deps but same result as with --force, here's a screenshot of that try:
[Also tried --legacy-peer-deps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXEPh.png)

Could you please direct me as to how can I can install this package. I'm using angular-cli 14.0.1, and the ng --version looks like this:

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.6

@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.6

@angular-devkit/core            13.3.6

@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.6

@angular/cli                    13.3.6

@angular/fire                   7.3.0

@schematics/angular             13.3.6

rxjs                            7.5.5

typescript                      4.6.4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Done, please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!